# Rails form does POST instead of DELETE after adding in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I just recently added the functionality to sort table columns with the following lines of code:

```
<table data-toggle="table" class= "table">
.  
.
.
<th data-sortable = "true"> Some header column </th>
.
.
<%= form_tag(sccm_destroy_multiple, method: :delete) %>
 .
 .
 .
 <%end%>
```

So after I added in the `data-toggle="table"` and `data-sortable="true"` lines (was working fine before I added those), my form started making POST requests instead of DELETE, any ideas as to how to fix this?

Also:

**application.js**:

`//= require bootstrap-table`

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the HTML generated form from the page?

According to [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark), you should have the following hidden field. Do you see that field?

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sccm_destroy_multiple" method="post">
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete" />
```

> The Rails framework encourages RESTful design of your applications, which means you'll be making a lot of "PATCH" and "DELETE" requests (besides "GET" and "POST"). However, most browsers don't support methods other than "GET" and "POST" when it comes to submitting forms.
>
> Rails works around this issue by emulating other methods over POST with a hidden input named "_method", which is set to reflect the desired method:

Comment: I see the first line that you posted but not the the second....weird, since it was working before the bootstrap plugin

Comment: Yeah that's strange but everything is debuggable. I searched their issues and didn't find anything on the form methods or problems with `delete`. Try their suggestions and if no luck, submit a bug. [bootstrap-table debugging](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#bug-reports)